# How to Insert csv files to database using python_ columns

Tags: python, mysql, sql, csv

This is my code

```
import pymysql
import csv

conn=pymysql.connect("localhost", "root","****","finance")
cursor=conn.cursor()       

print "done"
csv_data = csv.reader(file('naver_loan_output.csv'))

for row in csv_data:
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO 'daily_new' (date,cust_bal, cust_credit, fund_stock, fund_hyb, fund_bond )' 'VALUES("%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s")',row)
    conn.commit()
    cursor.close()
    print "Done"
```

And this is the error:

> File "D:\dropbox\Dropbox\lab\7_0218\insert_daily_new.py", line 13
>   cursor.execute('INSERT INTO 'daily_new' (date,cust_bal, cust_credit,
>   fund_stock, fund_hyb, fund_bond )' 'VALUES("%s", "%s", "%s", "%s",
>   "%s", "%s")',row)
>                                                ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax [Finished in 0.104s]

I tried a lot, but I'm not sure about the proper SQL insert query syntax. How do I get columns from csv? There are 6 columns in my csv file.

With this updated example, code works:

```
import pymysql
import csv

csv_data= csv.reader(file('naver_loan_output.csv'))

conn=pymysql.connect("localhost","finance")
cursor=conn.cursor()
print "Done"
for row in csv_data:
    #cursor.execute('INSERT INTO \'daily_new\' (date, cust_bal, cust_credit, fund_stock, fund_hyb, fund_bond ) VALUES({}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {})'.format(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5]))
    sql="INSERT INTO  daily_n (date,cust_bal, cust_credit, fund_stock, fund_hyb, fund_bond ) VALUES('2017-01-01','2','2','2','2','2')"
    cursor.execute(sql)
    conn.commit()

cursor.close()
```

So, I think the `for row` or `%s` is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Mainly, your quotes is the issue.

1. You need to escape single quotes if larger sql string is wrapped in single quotes; or simply wrap larger string in double quotes like your updated example. And note: the `SyntaxError` is a Python compile error (not MySQL runtime exception).
2. For parameterized queries, do not quote the placeholder, `%s`.
3. MySQL (and practically for all RDMS's) do not use single quotes to enclose table and column name references as you do with `'daily_new'`. Use backticks for names in MySQL. A few databases and the ANSI standard allows the double quote for object identifiers (not string literals).

Consider the following adjustment with a more efficient read process of csv file using `with()` as opposed to all at once as you have it with `file()`. And as shown with parameterization, you can prepare the sql statement once and then just bind values iteratively in loop.

```
strSQL = "INSERT INTO `daily_new` (`date`, cust_bal, cust_credit, fund_stock, fund_hyb, fund_bond )" + \
         " VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"

with open('naver_loan_output.csv', 'r') as f:
    csv_data = csv.reader(f)
    for row in csv_data:
        cursor.execute(strSQL, row)
        conn.commit()

cursor.close()
conn.close()

print "Done"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can try something like this:

```
query = """'INSERT INTO 'daily_new' (date,cust_bal, cust_credit, fund_stock, fund_hyb, fund_bond )' 'VALUES("""+row+""")'"""
cursor.execute(query)
```

Just see this code fragment from [CSV File Reading and Writing doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html):

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open('eggs.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
...     spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
...     for row in spamreader:
...         print ', '.join(row)
Spam, Spam, Spam, Spam, Spam, Baked Beans
Spam, Lovely Spam, Wonderful Spam
```

I hope it is useful to you or that puts you in the way.

Comment: thank you for helping me. But it doesn't work... really sad.

Comment: Also does this skip when the first row is actually the column names?

Answer (score 0):

There are three problems tripping you up:

1. String escape characters

In your code is that the single quote before **daily_new** is stopping the string and python is interpreting **daily_new** as a variable, which is not defined.

To solve this you should use the escape character "\" directly before each single quote you want *in* the string like this:

```
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO \'daily_new\' (date,cust_bal, cust_credit, fund_stock, fund_hyb, fund_bond ) VALUES("%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s")',row)
```

2. Column access

The csv module returns rows as a list. To access an element in a list (or row in your case), use bracket notation. For `row[0]` accesses the first element (column) in a row, and `row[5]` accesses the 6th column.

3. String substitution

The third problem you are facing is how to pass the values into the string substitution correctly. While there are many ways to do this, an easy one is the `format()` method. For example: if I wanted to build a string that says "Count is 1", I could run `"Count is {}".format(1)`.

In your case you want to add 6 values to the string, so you add a pair of `{}` wherever you want a value substituted into a string and add another parameter to the `format()` function.

### Putting it all together

So, to correct your loop code you would want something like this:

```
csv_data = csv.reader(file('naver_loan_output.csv'))
for row in csv_data:
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO daily_new (date, cust_bal, cust_credit, fund_stock, fund_hyb, fund_bond ) VALUES ({}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {})'.format(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5]))
```

Comment: Thank you. I thought similar way of you, so I was looking for how to get the many rows. I just copied yours. But It doesn't work too... I got the error:  (1064, u"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''daily_new' (date, cust_bal, cust_credit, fund_stock, fund_hyb, fund_bond ) VALU' at line 1")
[Finished in 0.264s]

Comment: I edited the last example to remove the escaped quotes which might be the problem. Since the table name has no spaces in it, it's fine without quotes.